# Save checkbox status of jquery datatable

Tags: jquery, datatables

I have used the jquery data tables plugin to create datatables. Now I'm trying to save the state of the check boxes. i.e. when i refresh the page check boxes which I have previously checked should be already checked.

This is my current code

```
  $("#tableBody"+tableName+"").html( '<table class="table table-hover dataTable table-striped w-full dtr-inline" id="'+tableName+'" data-plugin="dataTable" role="grid"></table>' );
  $('#'+tableName+'').dataTable( {
  "aoColumns": aoColumns,
  "aaData": aaData,
  'columnDefs': [{'targets': 0,'checkboxes': {'selectRow': true} }],   
    'stateSave': true,    
    'select': {'style': 'multi'},
    'order': [[1, 'asc']]  
  });
```

sateSave is working for pagination sorting functions.
But checked boxes are reset on page refresh or when navigated to another page and come back.

can someone explain to me what I am doing wrong here? I need the check boxes status to saved even when page is refreshed.

Comment: `stateSave` is only for DataTables-related features. If you want to save the state of the contents of the table you will need to do that manually. I'd suggest looking in to AJAX or localStorage depending on your exact use case.

Comment: The problem is a bit more complicated than you think :) Datatables doesn't handle these kind of things, you'd need to do it manually as suggested.

Answer (score 0):

[jQuery DataTables Checkboxes](https://www.gyrocode.com/projects/jquery-datatables-checkboxes/) plug-in handles `stateSave` correctly, see [this example](https://www.gyrocode.com/projects/jquery-datatables-checkboxes/examples/basic/state-saving/).

Please make sure you're using the most recent version, since there was issue corrected related to state saving, see [issue #64](https://github.com/gyrocode/jquery-datatables-checkboxes/issues/64).